# How to get/pass a variable into ajax so the chart can show up correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, postgresql

I have a code that that can be used to show a chart using chartjs.

```
$test = $_REQUEST['pass_date'];     

$res = pg_query("SELECT d.date, count(i.booking_id) from (select to_char(date_trunc('day', (date '$test' + offs)), 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date from generate_series(0,6,1) as offs) d left outer join booking i on d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', i.booking_from), 'yyyy-mm-dd') where product_name = 'EG' group by d.date order by d.date asc;");

//execute query
$result = pg_fetch_all($res);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}   

print json_encode($data);
```

this code use to get the data from database and show the date and count how much booking in that date. pass_date variable is from index by using **input** like this

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
<div class="input_1">
    <input type="text" name="pass_date" >
    <span class="text-muted" style="font-size:10px">YYYY-MM-DD</span>                                
</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="submitForm('home-guards.php')" value="Home Guards" class="btn green" style="margin-top:20px"></input>
<input type="submit" onclick="submitForm('event-guards.php')" value="Event Guards" class="btn green" style="margin-top:20px"></input>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $tfDate = $_POST['pass_date'];   
        }
        if(isset($tfDate)){ 
            echo $tfDate;
        }
    ?></form>
```

for example if i insert the pass_date to '2017-08-20' the result is going to be like this

> [{"date":"2017-08-20","count":"3"},{"date":"2017-08-21","count":"2"},{"date":"2017-08-22","count":"1"},{"date":"2017-08-23","count":"1"},{"date":"2017-08-24","count":"3"},{"date":"2017-08-25","count":"2"},{"date":"2017-08-26","count":"3"}]

and i have the javascript and ajax file like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url : "data_chart_booking_daily_eg.php",
    type : "POST",      
    success : 
    function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var inv_date = [];
        var jumlah = [];            

        for(var i in data) {
            inv_date.push(data[i].date);
            jumlah.push(data[i].count);             
        }
```

if i change the **$test** into specific date like '2017-08-20' the chart is doing perfectly but if i use **$test** the chart doesn't show up so now i don't know how to get/pass the **$test** variable into ajax so the chart can show up correctly. thank you for any help and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that `jQuery`? You aren't sending any data in your POST.

First, modify a bit that form to make value retrieval easier. Here I have added `id="pass_date"` attribute to input field:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
<div class="input_1">
    <input type="text" id="pass_date" name="pass_date" >
    <span class="text-muted" style="font-size:10px">YYYY-MM-DD</span>
```

Then send it in your POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "data_chart_booking_daily_eg.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: {pass_date: $('#pass_date').val()}, //this will get value of input field that
                                              //has id="pass_date" and send
                                              //as $_POST['pass_date']
    success : 
    function(data){
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, and it works. but what i want is the value of pass_date is from index, so when the user give some input, the value from the pass_date will be the user input

Comment: I have updated my answer to include value retrieval from HTML form input box.